# Using openCV library with Java works well on Linux but not on Windows

Tags: java, opencv, ffmpeg, javacv

I have a method that takes screenshots on absolute intervals (25%, 50%, 75% and 100%) from a video-file and save each of them to a separate .png-file. I use openCV with the JavaCV-Wrapper library to do that. The class/method of interest is:

```java
package de.stal.videoreporter;

import org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_core;
import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_imgcodecs.cvSaveImage;
import org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameGrabber;
import org.bytedeco.javacv.Frame;
import org.bytedeco.javacv.FrameGrabber;
import org.bytedeco.javacv.OpenCVFrameConverter;

class VideoThumbnailer {
public void createThumbnails(String videoname) throws FrameGrabber.Exception {

    FFmpegFrameGrabber g = new FFmpegFrameGrabber("videos/" + videoname);
    g.start();
    OpenCVFrameConverter.ToIplImage converterToIplImage = new OpenCVFrameConverter.ToIplImage();
    int length = g.getLengthInFrames();
    int fifty = length / 2;
    int twentyfive = fifty / 2;
    int seventyfive = fifty + twentyfive;
    int hundred = length - 1;

    //each frame of video
    for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {

        if (j == twentyfive || j == fifty || j == seventyfive || j == hundred) {
            String ss = "";
            if (j == twentyfive) {
                ss = "25";
            } else if (j == fifty) {
                ss = "50";
            } else if (j == seventyfive) {
                ss = "75";
            } else if (j == hundred) {
                ss = "100";
            }

            g.setFrameNumber(j);

            Frame f = g.grabImage();

            opencv_core.IplImage image = converterToIplImage.convert(f);
            String img_path = "thumbnails/" + videoname + "." + ss + ".png";
            cvSaveImage(img_path, image);
        }

    }
    g.stop();
}
}
```

That works fine on environment: Ubuntu 15.10 x64, Java v.1.7.0_101 and Netbeans 8.0.2 with Maven. So I exported the project to a runnable jar-file(with all dependencies included) and tried to start it on Windows 10 x64 via:

```
java -jar VideoReporter-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

On Windows an exception will be thrown when executing the .jar-file:

```
Error putting member offsets for class org/bytedeco/javacpp/avutil$Pool_free_Pointer.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.bytedeco.javacpp.avutil
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:472)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:417)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.avformat$AVFormatContext.<clinit>(avformat.java:2719)
    at org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameGrabber.startUnsafe(FFmpegFrameGrabber.java:391)
    at org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameGrabber.start(FFmpegFrameGrabber.java:385)
    at de.stal.videoreporter.VideoThumbnailer.createThumbnails(VideoThumbnailer.java:15)
    at de.stal.videoreporter.MetaReader.slurpMetadata(MetaReader.java:67)
    at de.stal.videoreporter.VideoReporter.main(VideoReporter.java:19)
```

My pom.xml is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>de.stal</groupId>
<artifactId>VideoReporter</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>de.stal.videoreporter.VideoReporter</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase> 
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
        <artifactId>javacpp</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
        <artifactId>javacv</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-csv</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0.rc2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

What might be the problem on Windows? In my opinion there shouldn't be a problem with access to openCV/FFMPEG-classes because they all have been included the .jar-file? Is this a problem with the classpath?

Thanks, Peter